# How to serve a view when database connection fails in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a page that refreshes with JavaScript every x seconds (ajax would be more ideal, I'm aware). The page is put on a TV screen to ideally run continously. I'm using CodeIgniter 3.

Once in a great while (like every few weeks or months), the database will connection fail, usually something benign like a midnight update by our hosting company.

When the database connection fails, view is not served, and the JavaScript that refreshes the page is not served, so somebody has to plug in a keyboard into the TV and manually refresh the page. This has gotten a little annoying.

I'd like to make it so when CodeIgniter is unable to connect to the database, it serves a view that contains the refresh javascript. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: a CRON job would be another, maybe more reliable option...

Comment: Maybe just check your response in javascript and do something according to it. Show us some js. Other way, try to make your app PWA.

Comment: @Vickel. I'm not sure I understand. I'm not refreshing the screen to change the state of a database or file system. It's just a page to view data. Unless you mean a CRON on the client, which sounds overkill.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 I'm not using ajax. When there's a database error, my view isn't served so there is no JavaScript on the page.

Comment: So your solution does the job ;)

Comment: `a page that refreshes with JavaScript every x seconds` ? so you query a database, CRON jobs do that perfectly, you could show an error page if the databse query doesn't return anything and display: "reloading within 4 seconds" or similar...

Comment: @Vickel It's a select query. Yes, the CRON could run the select query, but I need to display it on a TV, not in a CRON log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer while writing this question, but I'll share it because I don't see a duplicate.

In CodeIgniter 3, error view are found in the `/application/views/errors/html` folder. The file for database errors is `error_db.php`. Any HTML or JavaScript can be inserted here.